# When this error occur in react native : transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, ecmascript-6

When i try to install my react native app on device it shows following error :-
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/user28/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/exoplayer-core-2.9.1.aar/227c237efe9029fa4a76003d6795431d/jars/classes.jar

And i could not understand how to solve it. My app runs correctly but  after installing react-native-video dependency it shows following error.Help me to get out from this.

Comment: Can you add the dependency line which is throwing the error.

Comment: I solve it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```